# Extract items with specific property values

Tags: c#, linq

Using `C#` & `linq`, I want to have all items with duplicated id's in one list and another list with items that have unique id's.

**My initial list**

```
Id: 0 Name: ItemA
Id: 1 Name: ItemB
Id: 1 Name: ItemC
Id: 2 Name: ItemD
Id: 3 Name: ItemE
Id: 3 Name: ItemF
Id: 4 Name: ItemG
Id: 5 Name: ItemH
```

**I want a list with:**

```
Id: 0 Name: ItemA
Id: 1 Name: ItemB
Id: 2 Name: ItemD
Id: 3 Name: ItemE
Id: 4 Name: ItemG
Id: 5 Name: ItemH
```

**And another list with:**

```
Id: 1 Name: ItemC
Id: 3 Name: ItemF
```

Comment: *Welcome to StackOverflow!* Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why do you need to do this with Linq? It's possible (likely?) that the most concise solution doesn't require Linq.

Comment: oooh, -3 was enough to wake me up, I found something. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with a non linq solution for this problem.

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item(){Id= 0, Name= "ItemA"},
        new Item(){Id= 1, Name= "ItemB"},
        new Item(){Id= 1, Name= "ItemC"},
        new Item(){Id= 2, Name= "ItemD"},
        new Item(){Id= 3, Name= "ItemE"},
        new Item(){Id= 3, Name= "ItemF"},
        new Item(){Id= 4, Name= "ItemG"},
        new Item(){Id= 5, Name= "ItemH"}
    };

    var set = new HashSet<int>();
    var unique = new List<Item>();
    var dupes = new List<Item>(); 
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if(set.Add(item.Id))
            unique.Add(item);
        else
            dupes.Add(item);
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And a linq implementation could look like this:

```
var unique = list.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First());
var dupes = list.Except(unique);
```

Comment: Thanks Magnus, this is indeed what I also used after -3 votes for this question :(

Comment: @Stacked Have no idea why you got some many down votes, seems like a legit question/problem to me. +1 from me any case.

Comment: @Stacked Added a Linq implementation also.

Comment: thanks for your time and support :). At downvoters: come up with something useful instead of disappointing people, what's the added value of your -3?